# OdbcConnection ignores the ConnectionTimeout parameter

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, odbc

I need to ensure that, if database connection does not succeed in 10 seconds, the server will instead return an error.

This I did:

```
conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN="+DSN);
conn.ConnectionTimeout = 10;

try
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();
}
catch(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException e)
{
    /// Handle error
}
```

But the server still hangs indefinitely when the database is not available.

How to ensure the timeout is respected?

Comment: Does it work if you use the synchronous version? You should be using CancellationToken if you want to employ async cancellation semantics.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll look into it. Still I think it should throw an exception on it's own...

Comment: If DSN's support it, see if it makes a difference putting the timeout in the connection string instead of setting the connection's property.

Comment: @TomášZato Where you able to find a solution for this issue?